# 'libxslt1.1:i386': Input/output error

Tags: apt, dpkg

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libxslt1.1:i386': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Hi everyone, I've tryed to install some pakages using dpkg and apt-get and it always apears the same error (see on top) So what I've tryed for the moment:

- Reinstall libxslt1
- sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386; sudo apt-get update (this I think that it did't make sense if libxslt1 already installed)
- sudo dpkg --configure -a

I don't know how to fix that so can anyone help me to understand what is causing that and wich solution has?

Tanx!!!

Comment: When does this occur?

Comment: for example trying to install that pkg  sudo dpkg -i iwscanner-0.2.4.deb 

 sudo dpkg -i iwscanner-0.2.4.deb 

Selecting previously unselected package iwscanner.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libxslt1.1:i386': Input/output error

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do an

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then see if there are any updates to the packages first.

Comment: Hi, I've tryed this, and I think that I'd tryed before but after upgrading the same problem still ocurs. I mean, just before upgrade finish, the error appears again.. So what could it hapen?